# Magento2 call Static image on Minicart

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

Call static image or logo in knockout html in Magento2 Minicart, logo shows on home and category page but it is not shown on cart and checkout page in Magento2.

Answer (score 1):

First You Need to override this file in your custome theme file:

project/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

like this :

project/app/design/frontend/Magento/themename/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Please see this file where I have  added image in payment-image div

```
<div class="payment-img">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('images/name.jpg') }" alt="">
</div>
```

you need to put your image in this folder..

project/app/design/frontend/Magento/themename/web/images